# React - setState not resetting input

Tags: reactjs

Following my first React tutorial. My code seems to be exactly like the tutorial, but my input doesn't reset within a form component. The first time I submit, everything works fine, but the state holds onto the first value. Even when calling `setState` with a `console.log` in a callback, it seems like `setState` doesn't even fire. `this` is bound in my `constructor` function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TenantActions from '../actions/TenantActions';
export default class AddTenantForm extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

  this.state = {
    name: '',
  }

  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 onSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   console.log('1. On Submit click, sending addNewTenant action w/', this.state);

   TenantActions.addNewTenant(this.state);

   this.setState = ({ name: '' });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <form>
       <div className="form-group">
       <input type="text"
             className="form-control"
             id="tenantName"
             placeholder="Bob Smithers"
             value={this.state.name}
             onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
             />
    </div>
    <button className="btn btn-default"
            onClick={this.onSubmit}
            >Submit</button>
  </form>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` is a function. You have a typo (`=` extra) in the function `onSubmit`.

Replace `this.setState = ({...})` with `this.setState({name: ''})`

[More about setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

Comment: Ugh, a typo. Thank you!